# Ways to Arrange 7 things given restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

Let's say you have three $z$'s, two $x$'s, and two $y$'s. How many ways are there to arrange those $7$ variables given that $x$ and $y$ cannot be together?

Ex: $zxzxzyy$ and $xxzzzyy$ are valid while $zyxzyzx$ and $xyzzyxz$ are not.

I tried approaching this problem by finding the total number of ways of arranging the $7$ variables (without any restrictions) which was $\frac{7!}{{3!}\cdot{2}\cdot{2}}$ which is ${7}\cdot{6}\cdot{5}$, or $210$.

Then I could subtract the number of impossible combinations, and I did that by grouping one $x$ and one $y$ together to make a O. Then I just calculated the number of ways to arrange O, one $x$, one $y$, and three $z$'s. That was $\frac{6!}{3!}$, which is $120$. Then I multiplied the product by $2$ because O could either be $xy$ or $yx$ to get $240$ total combinations. Since $240$ is greater than $210$, I knew at once that I had over counted. To account for the over counting, I tried to use P.I.E. But at this point I had totally confused myself and now I have no idea what's the right path to take. (Maybe I should have divided the product $120$ by $4$ to account for the duplicate $x$ and $y$ in O?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may select three of the seven positions for the $z$'s, two of the remaining four positions for the $x$'s, and fill the remaining two positions with the two $y$'s in
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} = \binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2}$$
ways.  From these, we must subtract the number of arrangements in which an $x$ and $y$ are adjacent.

*A pair in which $x$ and $y$ are adjacent*:  Place the $x$ and $y$ in a box.  We then have six objects to arrange: $x, y, z, z, z$ and the box containing an $x$ and a $y$.  Choose three of the six positions for the $z$'s.  Arrange the remaining three distinct objects in the remaining three positions.  Arrange the $x$ and $y$ within the box.  There are
$$\binom{6}{3}3!2!$$
such arrangements.

*Two pairs in which an $x$ and $y$ are adjacent*:  The pairs could be overlapping, meaning that we have $xyx$ or $yxy$, or they could be disjoint.

Overlapping pairs:  Consider the case in which two $x$'s are adjacent to a $y$.  Then we have five objects to arrange: $xyx, y, z, z, z$.  Choose three of the five positions for the $z$'s.  Arrange the remaining two distinct objects in the remaining two positions.  This can be done in
$$\binom{5}{3}2!$$
ways.

By symmetry, there are also
$$\binom{5}{3}2!$$
arrangements in which two $y$'s are adjacent to an $x$.

Two disjoint pairs: We have five objects to arrange, three $z$'s and two boxes containing an $x$ and a $y$.  Choose three of the five positions for the $z$'s.  Fill the remaining two positions with the boxes.  Within each box, arrange the $x$ and $y$.  This can be done in
$$\binom{5}{3}2!2!$$
ways.

*Three pairs in which an $x$ and $y$ are adjacent*:  For this to occur, the string must contain either have $xyxy$ or $yxyx$.

Suppose the string contains $xyxy$.  Then we have four objects to arrange: $xyxy, z, z, z$.  Choose three of the four positions for the $z$'s.  The block $xyxy$ must fill the remaining positions.  There are 
$$\binom{4}{3}$$
such arrangements.

By symmetry, there are also
$$\binom{4}{3}$$
arrangements containing the string $yxyx$.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of arrangements of the seven letters $x, x, y, y, z, z, z$ in which no $x$ and $y$ are adjacent is 
$$\binom{7}{3}\binom{4}{2} - \binom{6}{3}3!2! + \binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{3}2! + \binom{5}{3}2!2! - \binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{3}$$

Answer (score 3):

The example is small enough to allow another way to count: case analysis by how the $x,x,y,y$ are arranged.

- For $xyxy$, there are $3$ "violations" so to speak, and the three $z$'s must be used to fill the violations, i.e. $xzyzxzy$.  This contributes $1$ valid string.
- For $xyyx$, there are $2$ violations which must be filled with $z$'s, i.e. $xzyyzx$.  After this, the last $z$ can be placed in any of the $5$ segments separated by $x$ or $y$ (including before the first $x$ and after the last $x$).  This contributes $5$ valid strings.
- For $xxyy$, there is $1$ violation which must be filled with $z$, i.e. $xxzyy$.  After this, the remaining two $z$'s can be placed in any of the $5$ segments.  There are two subcases:

  - the two $z$'s can be placed in separate segments in ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways, and
  - the two $z$'s can be placed in the same segment in $5$ ways,
  - which together contribute $15$ valid strings.
- The $yxyx, yxxy, yyxx$ cases are symmetric to the above, respectively.

Total number of valid strings $= (1+5+15) \times 2 = 42 =$ [same answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cbinom%7B7%7D%7B3%7D*%5Cbinom%7B4%7D%7B2%7D+-+%5Cbinom%7B6%7D%7B3%7D*3%21*2%21+%2B+%5Cbinom%7B2%7D%7B1%7D*%5Cbinom%7B5%7D%7B3%7D2%21+%2B+%5Cbinom%7B5%7D%7B3%7D*2%21*2%21+-+%5Cbinom%7B2%7D%7B1%7D*%5Cbinom%7B4%7D%7B3%7D) as @NFTaussig